# where does ILDASM show the .JPG, .XML, .txt files apart from the assembly and type metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, ildasm

Could anyone please guide me as to where does the ILDASM show the .JPG, .XML, .txt files (that are added to the project) apart from the assembly and type metadata
Regards

Comment: All you see is an .mresource in the manifest.  It can't decompile it, it is just a blob of bytes.